# I want to create a stored procedure using T-SQL that dynamically creates a table based on outside data that isn't vulnerable to SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection, create-table

I have a table which has a column that represents the name of a table we'd like to create.  There's a foreign key relationship to another table which has a column representing the name of the columns for the desired table (all data types assumed to be nvarchar).  I'm using a stored procedure to create this table.  Essentially what I'm doing is getting all of the relevant data from my tables, then building a SQL string up to generate the table, and finally using `EXEC sp_executesql @CreateTableSQL`.

`@CreateTableSQL` is generated through string concatenation like this:

```
SET @CreateTableSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + ' (' + @ColumnString + ')';
```

This leaves me vulnerable to SQL injection.  If someone were to use a `@TableName` value of:

```
C (t int); DROP TABLE MyTable;--
```

then this would drop MyTable (undesirable).

Can someone help me build this SQL and leave it invulnerable to injection?  Help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Write a function that limits @ColumnString to only the character set you want to allow in a table name.

Comment: Why do you need dynamically create tables like this at all? Once you have to resort to dynamic sql to create tables it also means you have to use dynamic sql to retrieve data. This seems like a recipe for really poor performance. You can use QUOTENAME to help with the table name but your columns are still going to be a challenge.

Comment: @SeanLange Ask my PM, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `QUOTENAME()` function which will enforce square brackets `[]` around the variables(Table and column names) and any value passed to these variables will only be treated as an Object name.

Something like ......

```
SET @CreateTableSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
                        + ' (' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnString) + ')';
```

Now even if someone passes a value of `C (t int); DROP TABLE MyTable;--` to any of these variables,  the whole value `C (t int); DROP TABLE MyTable;--` will still be treated as an object name.